# Latex can't find .sty with TEXINPUT exported

Tags: mac, paths, texinputs

My LaTeX document starts with this: `\RequirePackage{mymacros}`

`mymacros.sty` is located in a completely different dir. Following this [guide](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/%7Ewjh/tex/documents/environmental.pdf) which says I should export `TEXINPUTS`, I've added this line to my `.bashrc`:

`export TEXINPUT=.:/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/latex-styles/:$TEXINPUTS`

i.e. where `mymacros.sty` is located.

Then I run `latex myfile.tex`, but I get `! LaTeX Error: File 'mymacros.sty' not found.`

I don't want to store the .sty file adjacent to the LaTeX file, because I want multiple files in different dirs to be able to use the .sty file.

I've tried changing the singular `TEXINPUT` to `TEXINPUTS` in case that was the problem, but that resulted in the same error.

I'm running MacOS and my LaTex version is shown here:
`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)`

Comment: Do you run a Linux system? If so, I suggest adding the [linux] tag. Same for other OS. // May be it's useful to specify a bit more about your OS and Latex-editor you are using?

Comment: You are exporting TEXINPUT not TEXINPUTS. You shouldn't need this if you put personal packages and files in the personal tree. Did you install TeX Live via the MacTeX installer? If so you don';t need any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MacOS, the simplest approach is to put the files in `~/Library/texmf/tex` or its subdirectories. If for whatever reason you want to keep the files elsewhere, what I do is I open a terminal window, go to `~/Library/texmf/tex` (creating the directories if necessary) then

```
ln -s path/to/other/input/directory
```